# get a list of all variables defined outside a class by user

Tags: php

i have something like this:

```
class foo
{
   //code
}

$var = new foo();
$var->newVariable = 1; // create foo->newVariable
$var->otherVariable = "hello, im a variable";  //create foo->otherVariable
```

i can get in class foo a list of all variables defined outside by user (newVariable, otherVariable,etc)? Like this:

```
class foo
{
   public function getUserDefined()
   {
      // code

   }
}

$var = new foo();
$var->newVariable = 1; // create foo->newVariable
$var->otherVariable = "hello, im a variable";  //create foo->otherVariable
var_dump($var->getUserDefined()); // returns array ("newVariable","otherVariable");
```

Thanks!.

Comment: you want all variable of a class or all variable dynamically added to class with `__get` and `__set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using [get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) and [get_class_vars()](http://www.php.net/get_class_vars):

```
class A {
var $hello = 'world';
}
$a = new A();
$a->another = 'variable';
echo var_dump(get_object_vars($a));
echo '<hr />';
// Then, you can strip off default properties using get_class_vars('A');
$b = get_object_vars($a);
$c = get_class_vars('A');
foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
    if (!array_key_exists($key,$c)) echo $key . ' => ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: @diEcho - Can't he just use `echo var_dump(get_object_vars($this));` inside a class method?

Comment: oh, im a dork, i didnt use get_object_vars because im thought returns private vars too, but only returns a public vars. Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear though.

```
$var->newVariable = 1;
```

there are two possible contex of above expression

**1)** you are accessing class public variables.

like

```
class foo
{
  public $foo;
  public function method()
  {
     //code
   }
}
 $obj_foo = new foo();
 $obj_foo->foo = 'class variable';
```

**OR**

**2)** you are defining class variable runtime using [_*get*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and [_set](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set)

```
class foo
{
  public $foo;
  public $array = array();
  public function method()
  {
     //code
  }
  public function __get()
  {
    //some code
  }
  public function __set()
  {
    // some code
  }


}
 $obj_foo = new foo();
 $obj_foo->bar= 'define class variable outside the class';
```

so in which context your question is talking about?

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal? Imo it's not very good practice (unless you really know what you are doing). Maybe it's good idea consider create some class property like "$parameters" and then create setter and getter for this and use it in this way:

```
class foo {
    private $variables;

    public function addVariable($key, $value) {
        $this->variables[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function getVariable($key) {
        return $this->variables[$key];
    }

    public function hasVariable($key) {
        return isset($this->variables[$key]);
    }

    (...)
 }

$var = new foo();

$var->addVariable('newVariable', 1); 
$var->addVariable('otherVariable', "hello, im a variable");
```

And then you can use it whatever you want, for example get defined variable:

```
$var->getVariable('otherVariable');
```

To check if some var is already defined:

```
$var->hasVariable('someVariable')
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_class_vars()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php